# Show values on form

Tags: laravel-4

When adding form inputs on the page, we later need the currently posted data as if some fields didn't match the requirements so we show them back on the form to help user not filling it out again, and or showing data from DB if there is anything.

I use the conventional method of using ternary:

```
Input::old('name')?Input::old('name'):$data->name
```

To the form inputs:

```
{{ Form::text("name", Input::old('name')?Input::old('name'):$data->name, array("id" => "name", "class" => "form-control", "placeholder" => "name")) }}
```

This `$data->name` comes from DB and you know `Input::old('name')` already.

Is there any better way of showing the value not using this old method? Does Laravel provide some hacks about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is purpose of form-model binding.

```
// For creating model
public function create()
{
    $user = User::newInstance();

    return View::make('user.form', compact('user'));
}

// For updating model
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return View::make('user.form', compact('user'));
}

{{ Form::model($user) }}

    {{ Form::text('name') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

This does exactly what you want - fills the form with actual object data, or with $_POST data if entered previously.

Comment: How about inputs if we have an array of options within them? `{{ Form::text('owner', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}` what should be the default value? here's `null`